# Triggering antialiasing for webfonts in chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, webfonts, antialiasing

So we all know how crappy webfonts look with antialiasing disabled... I just found out that, if you're using Chrome, you trigger antialiasing at 49px or higher, however, with firefox it's set at 257px or higher.

Does anyone know if it is possible to trigger them at lower values?

And no, `font-smooth`, `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `text-shadow` techniques do not solve this issue.

I am using windows7 and the latest firefox/chrome versions as of this writing

Cheers
Sotkra

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 257px value? I don't observe a difference in rendering between 200px and 280px on Win7 with clear-type enabled.

Comment: Can you post the font import CSS? Some "auto webfont generators" (e.g. fontsquirrel) put SVG fonts at the top to support old Chrome versions, and they are rendered totally differently to WOFF / TTF.

Comment: This was ages ago with versions of chrome and ff I no longer have access to.